# Python - Flask Api exception

Tags: python, json, rest, exception, flask

i am currently working on my api and wanted to implement a mechanism that i can raise a custom exception at any point and return a json response:

```
class InvalidUsage(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.message = message

    def to_json(self):
        return JsonResponse(False, self.message)()

class JsonResponse(object):
    def __init__(self, success, data):
        self.success = success
        self.data = data

        if not success:
            self.result = {
                'success': self.success,
                'error': self.data
            }
        else:
            self.result = {
                'success': self.success,
                'data': self.data
            }

    def __call__(self):
        return jsonify({'result': self.result})
```

When i try to use it in any controller:

```
raise InvalidUsage('Some error ocurred').to_json()
```

it just prints a Traceback back to:

```
raise InvalidUsage('Some error ocurred').to_json()
```

But JsonResponse works perfectly fine. When i run:

```
return JsonResponse(False, 'Some error ocurred')()
```

it returns correct json to my browser.

But i need to get my exception raise somehow working.. so i can raise api exceptions at any point in my python-webapp(controller, service, validator, etc..)

Anybody could help me to figure out how to do this?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Flask specifically states that a custom error without an exception handler would cause a 500 server error:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/apierrors/
Have you tried implementing the handler and raising just the error, without calling .to_json() on it? I'm also not sure I understand why you would call .to_json() when raising the exception.

Comment: i implemented the exact same like in the documentation, but with same result

Comment: Why do you call .to_json() then? I mean probably  what you should do is call to_json from the error handler, not from the `raise` instruction

Comment: I don't see how your `raise` instruction could possibly work since `raise` accepts an object inheriting from BaseException and your are giving it a flask `Response` via `jsonify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to call the constructor of a parent class, you should call `super`

```
class InvalidUsage(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(InvalidUsage, self).__init__()
        self.message = message
```

Second, overriding `__call__` is just ugly and a bad idea. You should either implement an explicit method, or define a custom `__repr__` since JSON is just a string.

Third,

```
self.result = {
    'success': self.success,
    'data': self.data
}
```

is executed on both `if` and `else`. Why do you even have an `if`? Why not:

```
class JsonResponse(object):
    def __init__(self, success, data):
        self.success = success
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps({'success': self.success, 'data': self.data})
```

which makes this class more pointless than ever if it isn't used anywhere else in the code.

Fourth, when you want to raise a custom exception, you should raise the class `InvalidUsage` not a particular method in it.

```
raise InvalidUsage("terrible usage")
```

---

You should really think clearly about what you're doing here. You're throwing `Exception`s. You can't throw an instance of a `Flask.Response()` object as an exception. What you can do is throw your custom `InvalidUsage` exception, **catch it**, and then return your json response:

```
class InvalidUsage(Exception)
    pass


def horrible_code():
    raise InvalidUsage("something went wrong.")


try:
    horrible_code()

except InvalidUsage as error:
    return jsonify({"success": "nope", "error_message": str(error)})
```